# two members of array has the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x

How is this possible that the output color is BLACK in both members of array ?
What am I missing here.

Code :

```
url= u'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/{0}/inventory/'.format(listing_id)
r = requests.get(url=url, auth=OAuth1(ETSY_CLIENT_KEY, ETSY_CLIENT_SECRET,
                ETSY_RESOURCE_OWNER_KEY_READ, ETSY_RESOURCE_OWNER_SECRET_READ,
                signature_type='auth_header'))

rsp = json.loads(r.text)
rsp['results']['products'][0]['sku']=sku

rsp['results']['products'][0]['property_values'] = [
    {'property_id':513, 
    'property_name':'Custom property', 
    'values': ['red']}
    ]

rsp['results']['products'].append(rsp['results']['products'][0])

rsp['results']['products'][1]['property_values'] = [
    {'property_id':513, 
    'property_name':'Custom property', 
    'values': ['black']}
    ]
rsp['results']['products'][1]['sku']='1' + str(sku)
```

Unwanted output :

```
rsp['results']['products'][0]['property_values'][0]['values'][0]
'black'
rsp['results']['products'][1]['property_values'][0]['values'][0]
'black'
```

The output I need

```
rsp['results']['products'][0]['property_values'][0]['values'][0]  red 
rsp['results']['products'][1]['property_values'][0]['values'][0]  black
```

Comment: `append()` doesn't make a copy of the dictionary, it appends a reference to the same dictionary.

Comment: use `append(rsp['results']['products'][0].copy())`

Comment: @Barmar o man...... Is it that obvious !

Comment: @Barmar this really solved my issue.

Comment: @Barmar want to post it as an answer so I can mark as solved ?

Comment: There are a zillion other questions like this. It should be marked as a duplicate of one of them, but I don't have a good candidate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)